# Adding Attributes to Nodes from Dataframe in a Network

Tags: python-3.x, attributes, nodes, networkx

I asked this question before but after a comment I want to change it:

```
import networkx as nx
```

**What I Have:** a graph G imported in networkx from dataframe using by *nx.from_pandas_dataframe()*

**Problem :** When I used `nx.from_pandas_dataframe(dataframe, 'Sources', 'Target', edge_attr=True)` nx thinks all other colums rather then *Sources* and *Target* are attributes to edges.

**What I want to do:** I want to use some columns of dataframe as attributes of nodes.

**My Question :** Is there any easy way to do this(like `edge_attr=True` add many attributes with only one function)? If not How can I add many attributes to nodes from a dataframe?
For example:

```
Airline Sources Target  SLongitudeLatitude  TLongitudeLatitude  SPopulation NPopulation
Alpha   A           Z              1               10              101             111
Delta   B           Y              2               11              102             112
Gamma   C           X              3               12              103             113
Omega   D           W              4               13              104             114
Lambda  E           U              5               14              105             115
Zeta    F           T              6               15              106             116
Beta    G           S              7               16              107             117
Phi     H           R              8               17              108             118
```

Airline Column is attribute to edges but rest of columns (SLongitudeLatitude, TLongitudeLatitude and Population) are attribute for nodes.

Or can I add attributes to nodes from different dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Networkx can only take edge attributes from Pandas dataframes, but it isn't too bad to add the node attributes in a separate step, as this answer outlines:

[Load nodes with attributes and edges from DataFrame to NetworkX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558165/load-nodes-with-attributes-and-edges-from-dataframe-to-networkx)

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```
G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'Sources', 'Target', edge_attr=['NPopulation','SPopulation'])
G.edges(data=True)
```

Result:

```
[('A', 'Z', {'NPopulation': 111, 'SPopulation': 101}),
 ('B', 'Y', {'NPopulation': 112, 'SPopulation': 102}),
 ('C', 'X', {'NPopulation': 113, 'SPopulation': 103}),
 ('D', 'W', {'NPopulation': 114, 'SPopulation': 104}),
 ('E', 'U', {'NPopulation': 115, 'SPopulation': 105}),
 ('F', 'T', {'NPopulation': 116, 'SPopulation': 106}),
 ('G', 'S', {'NPopulation': 117, 'SPopulation': 107}),
 ('H', 'R', {'NPopulation': 118, 'SPopulation': 108})]
```